# Displaying correlation coefficients in bold with ggpubr Stat_cor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use `stat_cor()` to display the pearson correlation coefficients on a boxplot. To favor the visibility of the coefficients, I am trying to display them in bold. I am still quite new to R, and I tried to solve the issue by myself with this code :

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  stat_smooth(method = lm, aes(color = Species), se = FALSE) +
  stat_cor(aes(color = Species, label = after_stat(r.label)), 
  r.accuracy = 0.01, label.x = 4, label.y = c(8, 7.8, 7.6), 
  fontface = "bold") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey70", "gold", "green3")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
        legend.background = element_rect(fill="grey90", 
                                         size=0.5, linetype="solid"))
```

This method didn't work, and I couldn't figure out how to do it in `theme()`, even though I believe there is probably a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule: The `theme()` will have no effect on text labels. It sets the overall look of the plot and will affect only the so-called non-data ink. For text labels you have to set the font face in the geom or the stat. However, `stat_cor` uses `?plotmath` expressions to create the labels, i.e. make the R or ... italic. And in that the face of the labels can't be set or changed via `fontface=`.

Hence, to make the labels bold requires to create the label yourself inside `after_stat`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  stat_smooth(method = lm, aes(color = Species), se = FALSE) +
  stat_cor(
    aes(
      color = Species,
      label = after_stat(
        paste0(
          "bolditalic(R)~",
          "bold(`=`)~",
          "bold('", r, "')"
        )
      )
    ),
    r.accuracy = 0.01,
    label.x = 4, label.y = c(8, 7.8, 7.6),
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey70", "gold", "green3")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.background = element_rect(
      fill = "grey90",
      size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"
    )
  )
#> Warning: The `size` argument of `element_rect()` is deprecated as of ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use the `linewidth` argument instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Comment: I recently managed to remove the "a" in the legend. Maybe you are aware of this, but adding ` guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0)))` to your code will remove the "a". See [here](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/106)

Comment: Works well ! I was asking myself if there is a way to do the same thing but with the added p-values below the coefficients ?

Comment: Personally I would add the p values on the same line, which also easier to achieve. But if you want to the p-values below the coefficients I would use a second `stat_cor`. The reason is that `plotmath` does not support multiline strings, i.e. we can't use a line break. But there is also the option of using `atop()`.

Comment: @TarJae Easier option would be to add `show.legend = FALSE` to `stat_cor`.